# Why didn't the Jedi wear armour?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Jedi are known for wearing robes with hoods, and though it looks cool, I am pretty sure it doesn't provide any protection to blaster bolts.

Now I know the Jedi can deflect blaster bolts with their lightsabres, and all of Obi-Wan's 'uncivilized' thing but I am pretty sure armour would have been efficient during Order 66 when they were surrounded by many hostiles.

So, why do they not wear Beskar armour or something?

Comment: So uncivilised...

Comment: They are peacekeepers, if they were dressed for war it would dilute their message.

Comment: Because Beskar is hard to get--apparently the Mandalorians are to Beskar what DeBeers is to diamonds--and non-Beskar armor has no effect.  Why did the Imperial troopers wear that white stuff?  I haven't seen a scene where it offered any protection from any weapon in the franchise.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis, I did not mean beskar in particular I was just giving an example of an armour material

Comment: @A.bakker, they were peacekeepers but they also had the sith as their enemy, if not always they must atleast keep a spare for such situations

Comment: The Force is with me, And I am one with the Force; And I fear nothing, Because all is as the Force wills it.

Comment: Well, a big part of Order 66 was that it was supposed to be a surprise attack on the Jedi, orchestrated secretly and carefully for years to be triggered at the best possible moment. Other than wearing armor 100% of the time, how could anyone defend from that?

Comment: They did wore armor, during The Clone Wars both Anakin and Obi Wan left the robes for an Armor, as they already said, Beskar was hard af to obtain, so no Beskar, heavier plates of any other metal would be detrimental for their movement tho.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_armor

Answer (score 5):

**Nobody wears armour unless they are expecting to fight.** In our world soldiers didn't generally put on armour unless they were going to battle. Armour is uncomfortable. You don't wear it unless you need it.

**Additionally armour makes it look like you are coming for a fight.** If you show up for a peace negotiation, or a diplomatic visit, or a garden party wearing armour it is sending a message that you are expecting a battle. That can make the meeting/negotiation/party go much worse than it otherwise might, and put you in more danger than you would be without it (as well as not achieving your objective).

**Armour restricts your movement.** Jedi rely on their speed and dexterity to protect themselves, and armour might make that more difficult.

In short even if there might be some small combat benefits to Jedi wearing armour there are good reasons not to.

Answer (score 2):

> Why didn't the Jedi wear armour?

Well, Obi Wan did wear armor during the Clone Wars.  But as you stated, neither he nor any of the other Jedi needed it.

> I am pretty sure armour would have been efficient during Order 66 when they were surrounded by many hostiles.

Considering that the Jedi were caught completely off guard and were heavily outnumbered, having armor probably would not have helped much.  Maybe a few more would have survived, but most would likely have still been killed.

Keep in mind that the Clone Troopers and Storm Troopers all wore armor and were still able to (sometimes easily) be killed by blaster fire.  So, the commonly available armor didn't seem to offer that much protection against blaster fire.  And Beskar being difficult to acquire, is probably why it was rare to see *anyone* using it as armor.

Comment: but was there not something in between the commonly available armour and beskar?